# How to transfer data over SPI (I'm getting a null buffer)

Tags: c++, spi

I am new to SPI communication. I am trying to send 32 bit data. Here in this below code i have  my transmit data buffer of 32 bit unsigned, and initialized a dummy received buffer 32 bit long. I get the fact that SPI sends and receive data at the same time. I have set the Chipselect pin low and the MOSI pin high and the clock is set to the mode (0,1) in the applilet code Generator. My first idea was to send a master command to read a particular address from the slave but i receive a null buffer. Is there anyone who could provide me some suggestions?

```
u32 CO2_SpiDriver::getData(const u32 Buffer) {
    //#[ operation getData(u32)
    u32 transmitBuffer = Buffer;   //contains the data to be transmitted  
    u8 pBuffer_u8[4];
    memcpy(pBuffer_u8, &Buffer, 4); 
    u32 receive = 0U;  
    u8 pReceiverBuffer_u8[4];
    memcpy(pReceiverBuffer_u8, &receive, 4); //duummy buffer to receive data

        setCSpin(true); //Chip select pin active low   

        setMOSIpin(true); //set MOSI pin active high

        R_CSI20_Create();

        R_CSI20_Start(); //start the communication

       (R_CSI20_Send_Receive(pBuffer_u8, 4, pReceiverBuffer_u8));   

        return receive;


    //#]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: My suggestion is to provide more details, such as the platform and any libraries you are using.  As presented, we have no idea what the given functions do.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Here is the link which explains about the libraries in Detail   ... http://tool-support.renesas.com/autoupdate/support/onlinehelp/csp/V4.01.00/CS+.chm/CodeGenerator-API-RL78.chm/Output/cg-RL78-API-SAU26.html

Comment: Is this a Raspberry Pi? What are you trying to talk to at the other end? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Hook up an oscilloscope to the SPI bus lines and see what the bits are that you are sending and actually receiving.

Comment: @MarkSetchell My master is a RL78 micro Controller, slave is the pressure sensor.... I am trying to read an address value i have initialized my dummy buffer but while i receive i am receiving an empty buffer... which shouldnt be the case....as of now i dont have Errors but i am not receiving any value from the sensor for the particular command which i send

Comment: @ThomasMatthews okay i shall do that .. My next step was that

Comment: Have you set up the SPI bus controller for the correct bus width?  Some allow 1..32 bit width settings?  Do you need to change the chip select after sending the data?  Are the timings correct between master and slave?  Consult the pressure sensor data sheet to confirm.

Comment: Are you set up for full duplex or half duplex?  On some SPI devices, you send data and ignore the received data (half duplex).  On others, you send and receive and the same time (full duplex).

Comment: I generally don't use libraries for SPI bus communications, but access the hardware directly.  It's not complicated and many libraries are designed as *nix drivers and contain a lot of overhead code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am using full Duplex(sending and receiving at the same time).... and yes my chip select is active low while i send the data.... so i have made that always low so that i can continuously send and receive